# how to fix net.forward error in opencv using java

Tags: java, opencv

i'm trying to detect text in natural image, after googling i found this tutorial but it's in python code so i try to convert it into java, currently stuck with error:

"OpenCV(3.4.5) C:\build\3_4_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\concat_layer.cpp:94: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer in function 'cv::dnn::ConcatLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'"

`List  LAYER_NAMES = new ArrayList();
LAYER_NAMES.add("feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid");
LAYER_NAMES.add("feature_fusion/concat_");

List outs = new ArrayList<>();
//error at this 'net.forward' line
net.forward(outs, LAYER_NAMES);`

i don't have any basic about opencv and my knowledge in java also limited. sorry for bad english.